# Is there a way to make Eclipse continually refresh your package-explorer files?

Tags: eclipse, refresh

I know I can at any moment click on the root node of the package-explorer view and press F5, forcing Eclipse to refresh its contents. What I'm looking for is an automated way to do it.

I'm using some code generators and it's boring to have to select the root node and press F5 over it every time I'm generating code.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Preferences->General->Workspace->Refresh Automatically

Check the checkbox and apply, and it will automatically refresh.

Comment: That's it! It's a shame it still takes like 2 seconds to refresh, though.

Comment: Might be slightly faster in 3.7.  The new option says "Refresh using native hooks or polling" - if it's using native hooks now, and wasn't before, that's probably a win.