# Integrate Sublime Text with Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, sublimetext

At work, we develop Java applications and are using Eclipse. As a frontend dev I would like to switch completely to Sublime, but it's missing a feature of Eclipse, I can't work without it.

When developing, I had to build the project with Maven and publish it to a Tomcat server. Eclipse does this all automatically and also republish changed files.

I came so far, building the app with Maven and publish it to Tomcat with the Maven-Tomcat plugin. But with Tomcat 7 republishing isn't possible and changed files aren't copied to the working directory. So I have to leave Eclipse open and refresh its workspace everytime I changed files in Sublime.

Would it be possible to integrate this functionality into Sublime with any plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than deploy to a specific Tomcat 7 container that you ave set up yourself, I would instead use [`tomcat7:run`](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) to start a live container based on the unpackaged web app.

That should get you pretty much exactly what you are after.

If you don't mind switching to jetty as a server container [`jszip:run`](http://jszip.org/jszip-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) can get you even more, but I'm still working on getting that plugin to beta quality so ymmv

Comment: but I would like to use the same Tomcat instance

Answer (score 1):

What about this plugin https://github.com/nlloyd/SublimeMaven? I'll try it tommorow and then I'll let you know if it do the job (if it will work with ST3).

Comment: Sorry for that, looks like SublimeMaven is not working with ST3 so the only trick is tu use "Refresh using native hooks or polling":
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589539/is-there-a-way-to-make-eclipse-continually-refresh-your-package-explorer-files

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has a feature for this. Select **"Refresh using native hooks or polling"** and **"Refresh on access"**. You should select both. I have tried only selecting *"Refresh using native hooks or polling"*, but it works only when you keep open the specific file in eclipse and modifying it outside. *"Refresh on access"* also not working alone. With these options combined it works charmingly.

[image]

**PS:** *Native hooks available only in **Windows**. For **Linux** and **Mac** polling is used. I don't know how efficient it is.*

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. The workaround, is to open both eclipse and sublime, and instead of refreshing your project manually in eclipse every time you have made some changes in sublime, u can can use this plugin https://github.com/psxpaul/EclipseJava7Refresher to make the refresh automatically.

PS : As mentioned by @Kapil Dev S, eclipse (with "Refresh using native hooks or polling" checked ) can refresh automatically resources when changed, but it doesn't detect changes as soon as it happens (it takes some seconds, at least for me on Linux)