# sublime set up, to run a maven project with a tomcat 7 local host

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, sublimetext2

Im a frontend developer & love working with sublime (MAC). I have started working with other developers that work with java on Eclipse/IDEA on a project using Maven GIT & a Tomcat local host. The problem is im having to use Eclipse/IDEA in conjunction to work with these guys. Does anyone know of the best way I can use Sublime to access and edit the HTML CSS & JS in the best way. Any help would be well apreciated

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was:

[Integrate Sublime Text with Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119005/integrate-sublime-text-with-tomcat)

But I had to activate "build automatically" too in order to make it work.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more stylized syntax, I would recommend using package control to get JS, HTML, and CSS specific packages. If you are looking to use sublime to build Maven, then use package control to get [Maven](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Maven).

Assuming you already have package control installed, here are the steps to get the Maven package in sublime on a Windows or Linux machine.

> ctrl+shift+p
>   click install package
>   type in Maven
>   hit enter